# Automatically merge close vertices in Bezier curve

Tags: bezier-curves

**Is there a way to merge close bezier points to automatically close curves in poorly formatted SVG files?**

I'm creating some shapes from FreeCAD great sketch module in order to have constraint modeling (would be so cool to have it in Blender & inkscape):

[image]

As far as I can see, all the curves are "closed" (i.e. I don't have any place where two points looks to be a single point). However, when I export the SVG, I don't know why (FreeCAD bug?) but each curve (except the circle) have a single position in which the curve is cut. For instance, I can move one vertex to see it explicitely:

[image]

The problem is that once I merge all the curves with `Ctrl-J`, set to "2D" mode and "fill: both", only the closed curve will be filled:

[image]

I can manually close them via "Ctrl-B" to select the two points, then "F" to close. This works:

[image]

But it's quite long when I have many shapes (the longest part being to find the disconnected parts by moving each dot one by one), and I need to redo that every time I change my .SVG. Is there a better way to automatically merge close points in Bezier curves?

Comment: what about converting to mesh -> then merge vertices by distance -> then convert back to curve?

Comment: @Chris Thanks for the comment. It kind of work, but it has 2 annoying problems: first it adds many points to approximate curves which makes the topology more complicated and harder to edit later, and secondly due to these additional points the curves are not smooth anymore, and circles are instead made of many segments (this can be mitigated later by smoothing the shape, but smoothing does produce some artifacts at some places).